# Convert same sized arrays to object list

Tags: python-3.x

I have three arrays:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = [100, 200, 300]
c = [10.2, 20.2, 30.2]
```

How can i convert to below form in python?

```
result = {
    ['a', 100, 10.2],
    ['b', 200, 20.2],
    ['c', 300, 30.2]
}
```

Comment: What type of structure is result meant to be? a list of lists?

Comment: Yes, also can be a list of tuples.

Comment: Just an FYI, the current format of your `result` is not possible. It is a set of lists which can't be because lists are not hashable

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **zip**.

```
In [1]: a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
   ...: b = [100, 200, 300]
   ...: c = [10.2, 20.2, 30.2]

In [3]: list(zip(a,b,c))
Out[3]: [('a', 100, 10.2), ('b', 200, 20.2), ('c', 300, 30.2)]
```

Comment: Please try to only answer well-asked questions. In this case this is an obvious duplicate and already has many answers